# Use localStorage information in Woocommerce New Order email notification

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WordPress website, I use the Rentalhive theme and enabled the WooCommerce plugin.

I needed to somehow transfer information from which product they switched to buying another product. I chose (I can't say that this is the right choice, but so far it is the only one) to save the current link through `window.location.href` in the `localStorage` key `originalLink` where `const currentURL = window.location.href;`

That is, it looks like this:

```
let originalLink;
    if (currentURL.startsWith("https://vestcome.com/listing/")) {
        const productLink = currentURL;
        localStorage.setItem("originalLink", productLink);
```

Then I need to get the value in localStorage and send an Ajax request:

```
originalLink = localStorage.getItem("originalLink");

        // Sending data to the server using AJAX
        fetch(
            "https://vestcome.com/wp-content/themes/rentalhive/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php"
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: originalLink })
            }
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("Response from server:", data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error sending request:", error);
            });
```

In the admin-new-order.php file, I add my request processing code at the end :

```
// Getting data from an AJAX request.
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ($data !== null) {
    // Processing $data as an associative array (JSON decoded)
    $response = array(
        'message' => 'Data received: ' . print_r($data, true)
    );

    // Set the Content-Type header for JSON
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // Sending a JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

If necessary, I can add the entire code of this file.

Please understand me, I'm a beginner, and I'm studying the frontend side in general. I can't find anything similar on the Internet. Only settings at the WordPress admin panel level - without additional code.

I tried to pass information via json and text. I did not find any additional information with a similar problem. Only how to customize and change some content, color, etc. But not how to add additional code, query, or information.

I would be grateful for at least some information.

**Additionally:**

This is the main page.
[image]

Go to the product card.
[image]

```js
let originalLink;
 if (currentURL.startsWith("https://vestcome.com/listing/")) {
  const productLink = currentURL;
 localStorage.setItem("originalLink", productLink);
```

Click on advertise.
[image]
Select the option.
[image]
We pay.
[image]

The mail only contains information about who paid and what kind of advertising, but no information about the product. That is, in this example, the link https://vestcome.com/listing/fotohraf-u-kyievi-liubyj-zakhid-abo-po-domovlenosti/
[image]

This link is the way I came up with. To know which product to advertise.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will describe the details and what result I am trying to get. I will add screenshots for example. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: _"In the admin-new-order.php file, I add my request processing code at the end :"_ - and what exactly is that supposed to achieve? You are echo-ing the data you received, back to the client-side. If this _is_ even giving a valid JSON response, because like that template file will already generate output before your own custom code there? But that template file will not have any of the other data needed to send the email available, with your AJAX request - it _is_ a template file, so you should not misuse it in an attempt for any data processing in the first place.

Comment: Sending data to a specific script file URL is the wrong approach to AJAX in WP in the first place (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/). And you will have to _persist_ this data somewhere on the server side, so that it can be read from that storage location again, when the actual email gets send in the background.

Comment: @CBroe That is, I can save the link in a txt file and refer to this file when I send the order to the mail?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It looks the same as writing to me: you're the one who's doing it wrong, read the documentation. I want to know how to solve this problem correctly. Algorithm of actions.